Decode the contents of a Variable using the Base64 Decode Tag
I have been trying to decode a Base64 string in my API Response Body. When I put my variable into the Base64 Decode:

I can see that is create a Base64 for my variable name and not the value in the variable.
If I place the contents of my variable I see the decode:

How do I use the Base64 Decode to decode my ResposeBody Base64 value in my variable?
Thank you.

You need set Encoding and Charset
